# Removal of unwanted contour

Tags: plotting

I have plotted a contour plot. I want to remove the lower region. How can I do that?

```
ContourPlot[
 1.40 + 0.01 a^4 + 0.02774 a^3 b - 1.91 b^2 + 0.69711 b^4 + 
  a^2 (-0.208746 + 0.31 b^2) + a (-0.682 b + 0.354 b^3), {a, -5, 
  4.5}, {b, -1.7, 2.2}, Contours -> {1}, ContourStyle -> {Red}, 
 ContourShading -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, None}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) to limit the plot only to a desired region, for example to $y>-x/4$ which corresponds to the upper bean.

```
ContourPlot[
 1.40 + 0.01 a^4 + 0.02774 a^3 b - 1.91 b^2 + 0.69711 b^4 + 
  a^2 (-0.208746 + 0.31 b^2) + a (-0.682 b + 0.354 b^3), {a, -5, 
  4.5}, {b, -1.7, 2.2}, Contours -> {1}, ContourStyle -> {Red}, 
 ContourShading -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, None}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y > -x/4]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Interactively hide/show pieces using [`FlipView`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlipView.html):

```
flipView = Deploy @ DeleteCases[#, _Polygon, All] /. 
    l_Line :> FlipView[{{Opacity[.5, Blue], EdgeForm[Red], 
        Polygon @@ l}, {White, EdgeForm[], Polygon @@ l}}] &;

flipView @ cp
```

[image]

```
flipView @ cp2
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
labelPieces = Module[{i = 1}, 
    Normal @ DeleteCases[#, _Polygon, All] /. 
     Tooltip[c_, _] :> ({Red, #, FaceForm@Opacity[.5, Blue], 
          Polygon @@ #, Black, FontSize -> 16, 
          Text[i++, RegionCentroid[Polygon @@ #]]} & /@ 
        Cases[c, _Line, All])] &;

removePieces = DeleteCases[#, _Polygon, All] /. 
    Thread[Cases[#, _Line, All][[#2]] -> Nothing] /. 
   l_Line :> {l, FaceForm@Opacity[.5, Blue], Polygon @@ l} &
```

***Examples:***

```
cp = ContourPlot[1.40 + 0.01 a^4 + 0.02774 a^3 b - 1.91 b^2 + 0.69711 b^4 + 
    a^2 (-0.208746 + 0.31 b^2) + a (-0.682 b + 0.354 b^3),
  {a, -5, 4.5}, {b, -1.7, 2.2}, 
  Contours -> {1.}, ContourStyle -> {Red}, 
  ContourShading -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, None}]

Style[Row[{labelPieces@cp, removePieces[cp, {1}], 
   removePieces[cp, {2}]}, Spacer[10]], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
cp2 = ContourPlot[Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  Contours -> {.25}, ContourStyle -> Red, 
  ContourShading -> {None, Opacity[.5, Blue]}]

Style[Row[{labelPieces@cp2, removePieces[cp2, {1, 2, 5}], 
   removePieces[cp2, {3, 5, 8, 10}]}, Spacer[10]], 
 ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]